# Changing the React context from the top-level App class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I want to create asynchronous dialogs in Typescript (that will wait for the user interaction) that I could add from anywhere within my application. Starting with confirmation dialogs right now. I have a problem getting it to work so that `App` class could somehow store a new dialog into the `DialogsContext` and  `Dialogs` component will be notified on new dialog created.

I want to use my `showConfirmDialog` of my top-level `App` class to handle dialogs creation.

Please note that the `App` class is **not** an actual react component and I don't want it to be. It's simple a top-level class controlling the whole app that does eventually render all components.

How can I solve this?

```
export class App {
    public async showConfirmDialog(): Promise<boolean> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // NOTE: This is not an actual code - unfinished
            // How do I push new dialog into the confirmDialogs array in DialogsContext?
            // confirmDialogs.push(<ConfirmDialog onClick={() => resolve(true)} />);
        });
    }

    public async setup(): Promise<void> {
        const React = await import('react');
        const { render } = await import('react-dom');
        const Dialogs = await import('./components/dialogs');
        const DialogsContext = await import ("./components/context/dialogs-context");

        const app = (
            <DialogsContext.Provider>
                <Dialogs />
            </DialogsContext.Provider>
        );

        const rendered = render(app, document.getElementById('output'));

        return rendered;
    }
}
```

**dialogs-context.tsx**

```
const DialogsContext = React.createContext({
    confirmationDialogs: []
});

export default DialogsContext;
```

**dialogs-component.tsx**

```
const Dialogs : React.FunctionComponent = props => {
    const dialogs = useContext(DialogsContext);

    return (
        <div key="dialogs" className="dialogs">
            Total dialogs: {dialogs.confirmDialogs.length}

            {dialogs.confirmDialogs.map((dlg: React.ReactElement, i: number) => (
                <div key={i} className="dialog">
                    {dlg}
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Dialogs;
```

Comment: Are yoy having any error on the console?. You should not mix functional component and class component. Imports should be at the top of your file. You can try Material UI Modal: https://material-ui.com/components/modal/. It might already solve your problem

Comment: @MorloMbakop Nothing. This is not a class component like I said. This is a top-level class responsible for (among others) asynchronous setting up my application.  React allows that, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this sandbox that sort of does those things as I understood them.
https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-glitter-buj6x

Comment: Thanks for this. Pointed me in the right direction. I still got a problem with this however - how do I utilize the dialog store from outside component? Like, lets say I have a singleton, non-react logger instance and I want to send a confirmation dialog from there?

Comment: You can import the store instance (default import in the sandbox) and use that the same way it's used in the Controller-class example.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks, using store was the way to go in this case.